# Python combine two columns based on keys in the first column

Tags: python, excel, list, pandas

Let's say I have two column in an excel file as follows :

```
1 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5
5 6
1 3
```

My goal here is to achieve a mapping between the two columns. If the value in the first column is same in multiple rows, add the corresponding values in the second column. So my output here should look like : [1:6, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6]

Logic : The number '1' is present in 3 rows with the corresponding values 1,2 and 3. Hence, the total value for the key 1 becomes 1+2+3=6.

I started with an approach and went as far as this :

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Users\\a593977\\Desktop\\ExcelTest.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
data = [[sheet.cell_value(c, r) for c in range(sheet.nrows)] for r in range(sheet.ncols)]
firstColumn=data[0]
firstColumn=sorted(firstColumn)
secondColumn=data[1]
secondColumn=sorted(secondColumn)
print(list(zip(firstColumn,secondColumn)))
```

The output for this code is :

> [(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (4.0,
>   5.0), (5.0, 6.0)]

But the goal is : [1:6, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6]. How do I proceed further?

Comment: Your question screams pandas. Do you have it?

Comment: I tried using it as well. Couldn't do much with dataframes either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas. Try a `groupby`, `sum`, and `agg`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\a593977\\Desktop\\ExcelTest.xlsx', header=None)
res = (df
      .groupby(df.columns[0], as_index=False, sort=False)[df.columns[1]]
      .sum()
      .astype(str)
      .agg(':'.join, 1)
      .tolist()
)
```

```
print(res)
['1:6', '2:3', '3:4', '4:5', '5:6']
```

Comment: File "C:\Users\a593977\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2617, in _get_grouper
    raise KeyError(gpr)

KeyError: 0


This is the error I'm getting. Any idea?

Comment: @Sid Try again.

Comment: Still getting the same. Please help.

Comment: @Sid what does `df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\a593977\\Desktop\\ExcelTest.xlsx'); print(df.columns)` show?

Comment: Index([1, '1.1'], dtype='object')

So should I replace 0 with 1 in the code?

Comment: @Sid do `df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\a593977\\Desktop\\ExcelTest.xlsx', header=None)` and then run my second statement.

Comment: Using `pandas` is a bit of a ten ton hammer imo :)

Comment: @AKX 1. they already tried this with pandas, so no harm, and 2. it's a hell of a lot more readable than the soup in the OP ;-)

Comment: @coldspeed Sure, if Pandas is already in the toolkit, I suppose. :) Nevertheless, I added a stdlib answer for completeness' sake too.

Answer (score 0):

Without Pandas, getting from `[(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.0), (5.0, 6.0)]` to `{1: 6, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}`.

only takes a `Counter` (which is a specialized `defaultdict`):

```
from collections import Counter

x = [(1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0), (3.0, 4.0), (4.0, 5.0), (5.0, 6.0)]

sums = Counter()
for key, value in x:
    sums[key] += value

print(sums)
```

The output is

```
Counter({1.0: 6.0, 5.0: 6.0, 4.0: 5.0, 3.0: 4.0, 2.0: 3.0})
```

If you needed something other than sums, you could use `defaultdict`.

Comment: The main nuisance with a "pure python" answer is reading in that excel sheet. Good luck

Comment: @coldspeed `book = xlrd.open_workbook('file.xlsx'); s = book.sheets()[0]; x = zip(s.col_values(0, 1), s.col_values(1, 1))` isn't much of a nuisance (though sure, xlrd isn't in the stdlib). Anyway, both approaches work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas to read your data, followed by a list comprehension utilizing f-strings (available in Python 3.6+).

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', header=None)

df_sum = df.groupby(0, as_index=False)[1].sum()

res = [f'{i}:{j}' for i, j in df_sum.itertuples(index=False)]

['1:6', '2:3', '3:4', '4:5', '5:6']
```